# Android sub-activity

Tags: android

I have a Main activity with 3 buttons with these buttuns i pass values to my child activity number 2 and in child 2 i do something with these values.

Main class:

```
    uopgleuf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fullslot);
   uopgleuf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(UopActivity.this, fullslotActivity.class); // Go to child 2.
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("material", mat.getSelectedItem().toString());
        b.putString("dm", freesdia.getSelectedItem().toString());
        b.putString("endm", endmill.getSelectedItem().toString());
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
    }
   });
```

....

Child 2 class:

```
 public final static int SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE = 1;

  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
  mater = b.getString("material");
  d = b.getString("dm");
  endmill = b.getString("endm");
```

do something with these values.
In the same child 2 class i set on the end these code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(fullslotActivity.this, dataActivity.class); // Want to go to child 1 but it return to Main class.               
                Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
                extras.putString("snedebreedte", "ae");
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
                finish();
```

When i push the button in child 2 i would return the values to child number 1 and put the values in TextViews.

child 1 class:

```
protected static final int SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

And in the same class:

```
    @Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if(requestCode ==  SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
    snedeb.setText(b.getString("snedebreedte"));
}
```

Now my problem is when i finish child 2 the values return automaticaly to the Main activity.

This not what i want is there solution for this.

Were can i place startActivityForResult . I don't want to place it in the Main activity.

Placing the startActivityForResult in child didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when you finish child 2, the values return automatically in the Main Activity". This is the right process of startActivityForResult. Please, could you explain better the issue?

Comment: I want to return the values from Intent() in child 2 to my child 1 and place the values in Textviews. Now at this moment the values from child 2 return to the Main activity. This not what i want.